# Form autocompletion for Emacs Lisp forms

Tags: completion

Several approaches are available for symbol auto-completion with Emacs Lisp. Does Emacs also have completion functionality that, in IELM or in a buffer with Emacs Lisp code, provides form autocompletion? Such a function, given a form where the first element of the form is the symbol for a function, provides placeholders for the function arguments. This would be a function comparable to SLIME's `slime-complete-form`. For example, invoking the function with point in

```
(add-to-list )
```

would yield

```
(add-to-list LIST-VAR ELEMENT &optional APPEND COMPARE-FN)
```

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: Maybe try [Autotype](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/autotype/index.html)?

Comment: The expected arguments are shown in the 'echo-area' at the bottom of the screen. To me, it looks undesirable if this would always get expanded, because about half (or less) of the time you want to use the optional arguments (which then you'd have to delete, although that could be done smartly). Furthermore, I would say it does not make a big difference if you use e.g. `TAB` or just `SPC` to move to the next 'placeholder'. So... just look at the echo area.

Comment: @dalanicolai Agreed that always expanding is not desirable. My interest is in the occasional function which has an extensive set of arguments.

Comment: I took a hint from the Emacs source and used the `documentation` function in `help.el`: [elisp-slime-complete-form](https://github.com/thomp/elisp-slime-complete-form).